# 特定の授与日付で「バッジの授与履歴」の表示が崩れる

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### 不具合事象

バッジの一覧が記載されているページから、バッジの授与履歴 (例: [いい質問 - バッジ - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)) を見ることが出来ます。このページでは、「授与対象の投稿」が左、「授与日付やユーザー」が右に配置されていますが、**授与日付がすべて二桁になるとき、「授与時間やユーザー」が表示されているボックスが折り返し**ます。

この動作は、[いい質問バッジの授与履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)で再現していることが確認出来ます。

[image: 上は授与対象の投稿、ユーザーが左右に配置されているが、下はユーザーが折り返している]

---

To SE Team:

There is a design bug in budge history pages such as [this page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question); a user icon is located on the left instead of the right, if yy/MM/dd hh:mm of his/her awarded time are all two digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この問題は恐らく「授与されました」の翻訳が原文(英語)よりも文字列が多いためにオーバーフローを起こしているのが原因だと思われます。

該当箇所の翻訳を、より短い「に授与」に更新しました。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/7110

```
　原文: Awarded $relativeTime$
修正前: $relativeTime$ 授与されました
修正後: $relativeTime$ に授与
```

---

**修正前**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**修正後** (ブラウザの拡張機能で文字列を置換して確認)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]